# Can't extract needed information from NSDictionary after XML parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

My NSDicioanry object after parsing look like this:

```
 result = { 
         node = ( { id = { text = 27; }; 
         img = { text = "/upload/iblock/1a1/1a84f.png"; }; 
         name = { text = rtrttrrt; }; price = { text = 0; }; 
         type = { text = 0; }; }, { id = { text = 28; }; 
         img = { text = "e.png"; }; name = { text = gdd; }; 
         price = { text = 0; }; 
         type = { text = 0; }; }, 
        { id = { text = 30; }; 
        img = { text = "9.png"; }; 
        name = { text = gfdghfdh; }; 
        price = { text = 0; }; 
        type = { text = 0; }; }, 
        { id = { text = 29; };
        img = { text = "8.png"; }; 
       name = { text = d; }; 
       price = { text = 0; }; 
       type = { text = 0; }; 
     } ); }; }
```

i'm trying `NSArray *titleArray =[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"node"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"];` but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure it looks like this? Because it is full of mistakes..

Comment: `node` points to an array of dictionary.

Comment: @MarcMosby full version look like this: result = { node = ( { id = { text = 27; }; img = { text = "/upload/iblock/1a1/1a84f.png"; }; name = { text = rtrttrrt; }; price = { text = 0; }; type = { text = 0; }; }, { id = { text = 28; }; img = { text = "e.png"; }; name = { text = gdd; }; price = { text = 0; }; type = { text = 0; }; }, { id = { text = 30; }; img = { text = "9.png"; }; name = { text = gfdghfdh; }; price = { text = 0; }; type = { text = 0; }; }, { id = { text = 29; }; img = { text = "8.png"; }; name = { text = d; }; price = { text = 0; }; type = { text = 0; }; } ); }; }

Comment: Update your question with that information so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xmlDictionary[@"result"][@"node"][0][@"name"][@"text"]
```

It looks like node is an array, and you didn't delve into it in your attempt.

Comment: ` _titleArr = _xmlDictionary[@"result"][@"node"][0][@"name"][@"text"]; ` - does't work

Comment: name text is not an array, it's a string.  Are you trying to get an array of all the names?  You'll need to iterate over all the result/node entries.